# Add shadow to an SVG element, such as line

Tags: html, css, svg

So I'm pretty new to SVG but I started playing with a graph. The graph is from [here](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-make-charts-with-svg/). I've been searching for hours and did only find a half solution to my problem. As you see from the code snippet,  if you hover on the graph it "glows".  But I want that only the circles and the "joints" would glow when I'm hovering on them.

What I tried:

1. Using regular CSS shadowing
2. Using the code that makes "glow" the graph, but only on g elements.
3. Creating a separate SVG both: a) in the main SVG b) separately, and
   mixing them with `position: absolute`. (after this the positioning
   worked weirdly)

What should I do to make only the circles and the joints "glow"?

```css
  *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
  }

  html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;  
  }

  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,500&display=swap');
  body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  }

  .graph .labels.x-labels {
    text-anchor: middle;
  }

  .graph .labels.y-labels {
    text-anchor: end;
  }

  .graph {
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
  }

  .graph .grid {
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-dasharray: 0;
    stroke-width: 3;
  }

  .labels {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  .label-title {
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    fill: black;
  }

  .data {
    fill: #f86d36;
    stroke-width: 1;
  }

  .graph .dot-joints {
    stroke: #f86d36;
    stroke-dasharray: 0;
    stroke-width: 3;
  }

  svg:hover  {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 4px #f86d36e8);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 4px #f86d36e8);
  }
```

```html
<svg version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="graph"
    aria-labelledby="title" role="img">
    <g class="grid x-grid" id="xGrid">
        <line x1="90" x2="90" y1="5" y2="371"></line>
    </g>
    <g class="grid x-grid" id="xGrid">
        <line x1="90" x2="705" y1="370" y2="370"></line>
    </g>
    <g class="labels x-labels"><text x="100" y="400">2008</text><text x="246" y="400">2009</text><text x="392"
            y="400">2010</text><text x="538" y="400">2011</text><text x="694" y="400">2012</text><text x="400" y="440"
            class="label-title">Year</text></g>
    <g class="labels x-labels"><text x="70" y="15">15</text><text x="70" y="131">10</text><text x="70"
            y="248">5</text><text x="70" y="373">0</text><text x="35" y="200" class="label-title">Price</text></g>
    <g class="data" data-setname="Our first data set">
        <circle cx="95" cy="192" data-value="7.2" r="5"></circle>
        <circle cx="240" cy="141" data-value="8.1" r="5"></circle>
        <circle cx="388" cy="179" data-value="7.7" r="5"></circle>
        <circle cx="531" cy="200" data-value="6.8" r="5"></circle>
        <circle cx="677" cy="104" data-value="6.7" r="5"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="dot-joints x-grid">
        <line x1="95" x2="240" y1="192" y2="141"></line>
        <line x1="240" x2="388" y1="141" y2="179"></line>
        <line x1="388" x2="531" y1="179" y2="200"></line>
        <line x1="531" x2="677" y1="200" y2="104"></line>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this is what you need: I'm using an svg filter for the shadow.
To your code I've added `.data circle:hover{filter:url(#f)}`for the individual circles and `.dot-joints.x-grid:hover{filter:url(#f)}` for the group of lines:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
  }

  html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;  
  }

  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,500&display=swap');
  body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  }

  .graph .labels.x-labels {
    text-anchor: middle;
  }

  .graph .labels.y-labels {
    text-anchor: end;
  }

  .graph {
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
  }

  .graph .grid {
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-dasharray: 0;
    stroke-width: 3;
  }

  .labels {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  .label-title {
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    fill: black;
  }

  .data {
    fill: #f86d36;
    stroke-width: 1;
  }
  .data circle:hover{filter:url(#f)}

  .graph .dot-joints {
    stroke: #f86d36;
    stroke-dasharray: 0;
    stroke-width: 3;
  }
  
  .dot-joints.x-grid:hover{filter:url(#f)}
```

```html
<svg version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="graph"
    aria-labelledby="title" role="img">
    <defs>
    <filter id="f" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="shadow" x="-10" y="-150" width="120%" height="120%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5" result="blur"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feOffset in="blur" dx="3" dy="1" result="shadow"></feOffset>
      <feFlood flood-color="rgba(0,0,0,.52)" result="color" />
      <feComposite in ="color" in2="shadow" operator="in" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
    <g class="grid x-grid" id="xGrid">
        <line x1="90" x2="90" y1="5" y2="371"></line>
    </g>
    <g class="grid x-grid" id="xGrid">
        <line x1="90" x2="705" y1="370" y2="370"></line>
    </g>
    <g class="labels x-labels"><text x="100" y="400">2008</text><text x="246" y="400">2009</text><text x="392"
            y="400">2010</text><text x="538" y="400">2011</text><text x="694" y="400">2012</text><text x="400" y="440"
            class="label-title">Year</text></g>
    <g class="labels x-labels"><text x="70" y="15">15</text><text x="70" y="131">10</text><text x="70"
            y="248">5</text><text x="70" y="373">0</text><text x="35" y="200" class="label-title">Price</text></g>
    <g class="data" data-setname="Our first data set">
        <circle cx="95" cy="192" data-value="7.2" r="5"></circle>
        <circle cx="240" cy="141" data-value="8.1" r="5"></circle>
        <circle cx="388" cy="179" data-value="7.7" r="5"></circle>
        <circle cx="531" cy="200" data-value="6.8" r="5"></circle>
        <circle cx="677" cy="104" data-value="6.7" r="5"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="dot-joints x-grid" >
        <line x1="95" x2="240" y1="192" y2="141"></line>
        <line x1="240" x2="388" y1="141" y2="179"></line>
        <line x1="388" x2="531" y1="179" y2="200"></line>
        <line x1="531" x2="677" y1="200" y2="104"></line>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Alternatively you may want this instead:

```
svg:hover .data,
svg:hover .dot-joints.x-grid{filter:url(#f)}
```

When hovering the svg element apply shadow to the lines and circles.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
  }

  html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;  
  }

  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,500&display=swap');
  body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  }

  .graph .labels.x-labels {
    text-anchor: middle;
  }

  .graph .labels.y-labels {
    text-anchor: end;
  }

  .graph {
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
  }

  .graph .grid {
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-dasharray: 0;
    stroke-width: 3;
  }

  .labels {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  .label-title {
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    fill: black;
  }

  .data {
    fill: #f86d36;
    stroke-width: 1;
  }


  .graph .dot-joints {
    stroke: #f86d36;
    stroke-dasharray: 0;
    stroke-width: 3;
  }
  
    svg:hover .data,
    svg:hover .dot-joints.x-grid{filter:url(#f)}
```

```html
<svg version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="graph"
    aria-labelledby="title" role="img">
    <defs>
    <filter id="f" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="shadow" x="-10" y="-150" width="120%" height="120%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5" result="blur"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feOffset in="blur" dx="3" dy="1" result="shadow"></feOffset>
      <feFlood flood-color="rgba(0,0,0,.52)" result="color" />
      <feComposite in ="color" in2="shadow" operator="in" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
    <g class="grid x-grid" id="xGrid">
        <line x1="90" x2="90" y1="5" y2="371"></line>
    </g>
    <g class="grid x-grid" id="xGrid">
        <line x1="90" x2="705" y1="370" y2="370"></line>
    </g>
    <g class="labels x-labels"><text x="100" y="400">2008</text><text x="246" y="400">2009</text><text x="392"
            y="400">2010</text><text x="538" y="400">2011</text><text x="694" y="400">2012</text><text x="400" y="440"
            class="label-title">Year</text></g>
    <g class="labels x-labels"><text x="70" y="15">15</text><text x="70" y="131">10</text><text x="70"
            y="248">5</text><text x="70" y="373">0</text><text x="35" y="200" class="label-title">Price</text></g>
    <g class="data" data-setname="Our first data set">
        <circle cx="95" cy="192" data-value="7.2" r="5"></circle>
        <circle cx="240" cy="141" data-value="8.1" r="5"></circle>
        <circle cx="388" cy="179" data-value="7.7" r="5"></circle>
        <circle cx="531" cy="200" data-value="6.8" r="5"></circle>
        <circle cx="677" cy="104" data-value="6.7" r="5"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="dot-joints x-grid" >
        <line x1="95" x2="240" y1="192" y2="141"></line>
        <line x1="240" x2="388" y1="141" y2="179"></line>
        <line x1="388" x2="531" y1="179" y2="200"></line>
        <line x1="531" x2="677" y1="200" y2="104"></line>
    </g>
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> Can you explain it in a little more details

In the `<defs>` I've added an svg filter.  This filter first is creating a blur `feGaussianBlur`. You may need to change the `stdDeviation` in order to change the aspect of the shadow.

Next is offsetting the the previously created blur `feOffset`:  You may need to change the `dx="3"`and  `dy="1"` attributes in order to move the shadow.

Then `feFlood` and `feComposite` are used to add a color to the shadow. In this case I'm using a semitransparent black, but you can use the color you want.

I'm using this filter to apply the shadow only to those elements you want: `filter:url(#f)` - where f is the filter's id

Comment: This  is exactly what I needed! Can you explain it in a little more details?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an explanation. Please take a look